# How to use localStorage in angular universal?

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-universal, angular-local-storage

I am using @angular v4.0.3 and webpack 2.2.0.

It was working fine using [Auler](http://ium.com/@evertonrobertoauler/angular-4-universal-app-with-angular-cli-db8b53bba07d) post but as I included localStorage it stopped working.
Is there any way to make it work or any module for localStorage in angular universal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good way is to make `localStorage` an injectable and provide different implementations for it.

An abstract class that reflects [`Storage` API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.3.3/lib/lib.d.ts#L15751-L15760) can be used as a token:

```
export abstract class LocalStorage {
    readonly length: number;
    abstract clear(): void;
    abstract getItem(key: string): string | null;
    abstract key(index: number): string | null;
    abstract removeItem(key: string): void;
    abstract setItem(key: string, data: string): void;
    [key: string]: any;
    [index: number]: string;
}
```

Then for browser app module it is

```
export function localStorageFactory() {
  return localStorage;
}
...
{ provide: LocalStorage, useFactory: localStorageFactory }
```

And for server app module `localStorage` can be replaced with some implementation, like [`node-storage-shim`](https://github.com/mnahkies/node-storage-shim) for in-memory storage:

```
{ provide: LocalStorage, useClass: StorageShim }
```

Using DI instead of global persistent storage also makes testing easier.

Comment: Thanks estus , By now I just create a work around with platformID , as I was not storing much of data just a token. I will try this solution as well.

Comment: Yes, a provider is just a cleaner way to do this. Of course, platformID can be used in provider, but this will just result in having StorageShim in browser bundle, where you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because using Angular Universal for Server Side Rendering, the Angular app runs in both the Nodejs server and the client browser. At this point, the server app does not have a reference to the localStorage object, because it is only available on the client-side.

There's an article I wrote about this with the solution implemented: [How to use localStorage on Angular 9 Universal (SSR)](https://medium.com/@santibarbat/how-to-use-localstorage-with-angular-9-universal-ssr-517578615637)

Answer (score 0):

Angular Universal Set Localstorage using simple Platform Browser or Platform Server
Here is the component file

**components.ts**

```
import {  PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  locale_Menu: any = [];
  defaultURL: any;
  defaultURLpath: any;
  private isBrowser: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private dom: Document,
    private router: Router,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.generalAppSettings.subscribe((location: any) => {
      this.locale_Menu = location.localeMenu.continents;
    });
    this.defaultURL = new URL(this.dom.URL);
    this.defaultURLpath = this.defaultURL?.pathname.split('/');
    if (this.defaultURLpath.length == 2) {
      if (this.isBrowser) {
        var retrievedLocale = localStorage?.getItem('preferredLocale');

        if (retrievedLocale) {
          const navigateURL = this.defaultURL?.pathname.replace(
            this.defaultURLpath[1],
            retrievedLocale
          );
          this.router.navigate([navigateURL]);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate([this.defaultURL]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  changeLocale(category: any): void {
    const locale = this.coreService.locales.find((l) => l.code === category);
    if (locale) {
      let _URL = this.defaultURL.pathname.replace(
        this.defaultURL.pathname.split('/')[1],
        locale.code
      );
      if (this.defaultURLpath.length == 2) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('preferredLocale', locale.code);
      }

      this.router.navigate([_URL]).then(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    }
  }
}
```